# Undefined reference when linking with Boost using g++-4.9 on a g++-5-ish distribution

Tags: gcc, boost, static-linking, boost-program-options, gcc5

I've written the following groundbreaking application:

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    boost::program_options::options_description generic_options("foo");
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to build this on Debian Stretch, on which the default compiler is GCC 5.3.1-5, and the installed version of Boost is 1.58.0.

However, for reasons which I will not go into here (which [would be apparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34970513/problems-linking-cuda-compiled-with-boost-using-code?lq=1) had this not been a MCVE), I need to compile and link the binary using `g++-4.9`, not `g++-5.3`. Compiling works fine, but when I try to link, this is what happens:

```
/usr/bin/g++-4.9   -Wall -std=c++11   CMakeFiles/tester3.dir/src/altmain2.cpp.o  -o bin/tester3 -rdynamic -lboost_log -lboost_system -lboost_program_options 
CMakeFiles/tester3.dir/src/altmain2.cpp.o: In function `main':
altmain2.cpp:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
```

- Is this due to some ABI incompatibility between gcc 4 and 5?
- If so, is there any way to get around it other than building my own version of Boost?
- If not, what could cause this?

Comment: does it work when you build boost using gcc-4? also have a look at http://developerblog.redhat.com/2015/02/05/gcc5-and-the-c11-abi/

Comment: @m.s.: My gcc-4 is gcc-4.9 and that's what doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this due to some ABI incompatibility between gcc 4 and 5?

Looks like it is. By default GCC 5 uses a new ABI for several important standard library classes, including `std::basic_string` template (and thus also `std::string`). Unfortunately it would be impossible to make std::string fully conform to C++11 and later without breaking the ABI.

libstdc++ implements dual ABI, so that binaries compiled with older versions of GCC will link (and work correctly) with the new library. See this [post](https://developerblog.redhat.com/2015/02/05/gcc5-and-the-c11-abi/) by Jason  Merrill (the maintainer of GCC's C++ front end) for details.

> If so, is there any way to get around it other than building my own
>   version of Boost?

Probably not. Boost depends on the new implementation of `std::string` and does not provide backward compatibility (unlike libstdc++). This problem is [mentioned](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=797917) in Debian bugtracker.

Comment: I would think the distribution should then provide at least some central C++ libraries in the old ABI as well - as optional packages at least. Anyway, +1 for the answer but no accept in case someone can offer some kind of workaround.

Comment: Mikhail, am I to understand that only an older version of boost would help me?

Comment: No, you can recompile any version of Boost with GCC 4.9 and it should work fine.